# User-Agent OAuth Authentication doesn't provide expires_in data

Tags: rest-api, oauth2

I'm using the [User-Agent OAuth Authentication work-flow](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/intro_understanding_user_agent_oauth_flow.htm), and when receiving the authentication code, Salesforce is not sending me the `expires_in` data. Here's what my Salesforce response looks like.

*A line break at every parameter was added for readability*

```
https://localhost/index.html#
access_token=mytoken
&instance_url=myurl
&id=myurl/id
&issued_at=1404739540704
&signature=mysig
&scope=myscope
&token_type=Bearer
```

Why am I not getting the `expires_in` value?